# Django - Need help for TemplateView: Queryset and not updating

Tags: django, django-views

I am building a TemplateView with 2 forms, one to allow user to select the customer (CustomerForm) and another to add the order (OrderForm) for the customer.

Code:

```
class DisplayOrdersView(TemplateView): 
    template_name = 'orders/orders_details_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
        context = kwargs 
        context['shippingdetailsform'] = ShippingDetailsForm(prefix='shippingdetailsform')
        context['ordersform'] = OrdersForm(prefix='ordersform')
        return context

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DisplayOrdersView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) 

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context) 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        profile=request.user.get_profile()
        if context['shippingdetailsform'].is_valid():
            instance = context['shippingdetailsform'].save(commit=False)
            instance.profile = profile
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'orders for {0} saved'.format(profile))
        elif context['ordersform'].is_valid():
            instance = ordersform.save(commit=False)
            shippingdetails, created = shippingdetails.objects.get_or_create(profile=profile)
            shippingdetails.save()
            instance.user = customer
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'orders details for {0} saved.'.format(profile))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error(s) saving form')
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Firstly, I can't seem to load any existing data into the forms. Assuming a onetoone relationship between UserProfile->ShippingDetails (fk: UserProfile)->Orders (fk:ShippingDetails), how can I query the appropriate variables into the form on load?

Also, how can I save the data? It throws an error when saving and I have been unable to retrieve useful debug information.

Is my approach correct for having multiple forms in a templateview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the POST data into the forms at any point. You need to do this when you instantiate them. I would move the instantiation out of `get_context_data` and do it in `get` and `post`: the first as you have it now, and the second passing `request.POST`.

Also note that you probably want to check both forms are valid before saving either of them, rather than checking and saving each in turn. The way you have it now, if the first one is valid it won't even check the second, let alone save it, so you won't get any errors on the template if the first is valid but the second is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the help, think I understand how it works now. I may allow only one form to be saved instead of submitting both at the same time, will rethink logic there. Takes a while to get used to how django operates, very different from what I'm used to (desktop applications).